# Preposition "of " for boring or without it

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence-construction

My friend: hey ! What's up?

Me : nothing, i'm bored of waiting for favorite show's new episodes.

Friend : Oh, when are they going to air it on tv ?

Me: there's still a month for that

Friend: that sucks !

Here in this conversation is "im bored of waiting " grammatically correct ?

Or i should've said i'm bored waiting ?

Do both these sentences mean same things ?

Comment: Please be careful with your punctuation and capitalization etc. Although we can clearly understand your meaning, it would be better to correct them. **Imaginge sawing an sentense like thiss.**

Comment: First, you need to capitalize the first letter of every sentence. Second, you don't need a space before punctuation marks. (However, the French do, which I learned later from a comment by Michael Harvey). Third, the pronoun **I** should always be capitalized if it's used as a pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

You can say, "I'm tired of waiting," but if you want to focus on boredom, you might say, "I'm waiting and it's boring," or "I'm waiting and I'm getting bored", or "I'm waiting and it's beginning to bore me."

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. Are those sentences correct or not? They haven't asked for re-write suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

They're both correct, and they mean roughly the same thing.

"*I'm bored of waiting*" means I'm bored because I'm waiting.

"*I'm bored waiting*" means I'm bored and I'm waiting. The listener should easily understand that you're bored *because* you're waiting, but it's only implied, not explicit

Comment: When I was younger it was always 'bored with', or 'bored by'. 'Bored of' was seen as non-standard, and liable to be corrected by teachers. I now see that Macmillan Dictionary says 'So which is right: bored with, or bored of? Well, many people still regard “bored of” as incorrect, but really it’s a generational thing.  What our evidence shows is that bored with and bored of are now used with almost equal frequency, but that among younger people “bored of” is more common.  Both are acceptable, but it’s good to be aware that not everyone will accept “bored of” - at least, not yet.'

Comment: Lexico says 'It [bored of] represents a perfectly logical development of the language, and was probably formed on the pattern of expressions such as tired of or weary of. Nevertheless, some people dislike it, and it’s not fully accepted in standard English. It’s best to avoid using it in formal writing.'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey For me, a Canadian, "of" is by far the most natural and common preposition after "bored", but that doesn't seem to be the case globally: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=so+bored+of%2Cso+bored+with%2Cso+bored+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cso%20bored%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20bored%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20bored%20by%3B%2Cc0)